# Page performance: jquery + prototype.js

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I am putting together a [static website](http://atwebpresence.com/client/orto/) that uses a couple of jquery plugins plus a AJAX slide-down tab.
The issue I have is regarding what I believe is bad practice I follow when implementing the two together.
I have this weird effect on page load whereby the tabs are displayed for the first couple of seconds or so.
I would really appreciate if somebody could help e to figure-out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your default css has the tabs visible and the initialization of the JS code is what hides the tabs. What you're seeing is the normal state of the page before the JS kicks in. Your css should have them default to the 'hidden' or 'off' state, and the JS should be responsible for showing the tabs when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @dontGoPlastic's answer, you should initialize your tab panels in your css with your properties for `position: absolute`, `top: -224px`, and `z-index` (you probably don't **have** to define `display: block` because that's the natural display type for a div.

This will not only initialize your panels out of sight (whether js has loaded or not), but it'll also allow you to just `.animate()` your divs' `top` property, rather than having to set `position`, `z-index`, and `display` each time you run the method.